# Insert text to the beginning of all cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have an excel file in which I have a filled column A with numeric values, I would like to add the text "dt" to the values before the numeric value. Of course, text dt would be added in the entire column where values exist. Unfortunately, something in my code does not work

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports Excel
Imports System.IO.FileStream
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel


Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button5_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Button5.Click

Dim oExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Dim oBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

Dim oSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\PC\Desktop\1.xlsx")

oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)


Dim rg21 = oSheet.Columns("A:A")

rg21.Select()
rg21.NumberFormat = "@"

rg21 = "dt" & rg21

oBook.Save()

oExcel.Quit()

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook)

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel)

oBook = Nothing

oExcel = Nothing


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: did you try: rg21.value = "dt" & rg21?

Comment: it still does not work

Comment: what if you try  Dim rg21 = oSheet.Columns("A1")  rg21 = "dt" & rg21?
it works?

Comment: try also,   rg21.Formula = "dt" & rg21?

Comment: the same does not work

Comment: I would follow @gary solution

Answer (score 2):

I would use a **loop**.  In Excel VBA:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Columns(1).Cells.SpecialCells(2)
    For Each rr In r
        rr.Value = "dt" & rr.Value
    Next rr
End Sub
```

Adapt this to VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through the cells with value in `rg21`. 
This is the slow version of the loop, as far as you loop through all the 1.000.000+ cells in column A:

```
For Each rg In rg21.Cells
    If Len(rg) Then
        rg = "dt" & rg
    End If
Next rg
```

If you want if faster it would be easier to loop only through the cells with values in the first column. Like the example from *@Gary's Student*:

```
Set r = Columns(1).Cells.SpecialCells(2)
```